# Remove tags without a specific meta key from "choose from the most used tags"

Tags: filters, hooks, tags, actions, taxonomy-meta

I'm trying to only show the tags that are associated to the currently logged in author; I've got this 99% working, but the author can still choose tags associated to other users via the "Choose from the most used tags" link.

How can I edit this to exclude any tags whose meta tag "author" does not match the currently logged in user's ID?

[I'm using this solution to limit everything else.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/217297/24566)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that tag cloud seems to be a regular tag cloud generated by an AJAX request. This box appears to be the only place a tagcloud is generated via AJAX, so we can use that knowledge to use the [`get_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/tag_cloud_sort/) filter to filter any term queries performed in that AJAX request.

```
function wpse_277075_filter_tag_cloud( $terms, $taxonomies, $args, $term_query ) {
    if ( is_admin() && isset( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] === 'get-tagcloud' ) {
        $args['meta_query'] = array(
            array(
                'key'   => 'author',
                'value' => get_current_user_id(),
            )
        );

        $terms = $term_query->query( $args );

        return $terms;
    }

    return $terms;
}
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'wpse_277075_filter_tag_cloud', 10, 4 );
```

Inside the `get_terms` filter callback, I've checked for the `$_POST['action']` variable because this will tell us if we're in the AJAX request. Then we re-perform the tag query, but this time with a `meta_query` filtering the results.

**Note:** This code assumes that the author is set via a `meta_key` of `author` which is set to a user ID.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! I was overthinking it, trying to find a hook specific to the editor :)